# Wireless adapter randomly chooses to set encryption

Tags: windows-xp, wireless-access-point

Using Windows XP SP3, updated drivers yesterday, "Belkin Wireless G+ MIMO" or something router + adapters.

But specifically:

When the Encryption says enabled, the network connects fine.

[image]

When it's disabled it's a hassle to get it to enabled. In the connection Properties (right click in Network Connections, Properties), it's configured to connect to the right network, and uses WPA2-PSK (with key loaded) and AES encryption.

Repairing the connection is 100% hit and miss with it sometimes choosing Enabled, and working, and sometimes Disabled.

Is there anything specific I can look for that would ensure encryption is on, instead of it randomly choosing Disabled?

Comment: ANYTIME your are connected to a WPA/WPA2 secured network the traffic is encrypted... It sounds like you are losing connection to the network. Few things to check: Wireless router (are other clients able to maintain stable connection? test with continuous ping), Wireless card (make sure it is not malfunctioning, test by connecting to different wireless network).